# How to stretch image to the screen borders by width?

Tags: flutter

I need to show image  with a width of a screen, but when the image is smaller it does not strech to the screen edges.

```
CachedNetworkImage _getImage(String link, BuildContext context) {
    return CachedNetworkImage(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      imageUrl: link,
      placeholder: (context, url) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
    );
  }
```

and `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,` - does not stretch the image but just put it in the center of screen width

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          // outer column
          children: [
            _getImage(imageLink, context),
            ...
```

Comment: check `CachedNetworkImage.fit` property

Comment: great observation @pskink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these two modifications:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
       fit: BoxFit.fitWidth // or any other fitting option
   ),
```

and

```
Column(
       crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          // outer column
          children: [
            _getImage(imageLink, context),
            ...
```